# What is the maximum Vref allowed on LM431?

Tags: opto-isolator, voltage-measurement

I was looking at the answer given by [Jasen Слава Україні](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/13590/jasen-%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%a3%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%97%d0%bd%d1%96) in this thread [High Voltage (0-600V) DC Voltage Sensing, Shared Ground with Isolated Converter and HV-](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/486172/high-voltage-0-600v-dc-voltage-sensing-shared-ground-with-isolated-converter/666523?noredirect=1#comment1774187_666523)

[image]

The author needs to detect a voltage above 60 V from a 0-600 V supply.

As I am working on a project where I need something similar, there is one thing that is unclear:

What is the max. V<sub>REF</sub> of the [LM431](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm431.pdf)?

If the output is powered at 5 V, is V<sub>REF</sub> allowed to be over this voltage?

The 500 kΩ/22 kΩ divider will give the 2.5 V reference at 60 V, but at 600 V the V<sub>REF</sub> will be 25 V. Will the LM431 tolerate this voltage if the output is working at 5 V?

In my case I need to detect voltage above 18 V from a supply that can go up to 100 V.

Comment: Thanks for the edit [Velvel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/301846/velvel)

Answer (score 5):

Because it's constrained by either I<sub>K</sub> or I<sub>REF</sub>.

Notice the equivalent circuit:

[image: LM431 block diagram]

<sub>From LM431 datasheet, Fig.10 (p.10)</sub>

This doesn't show all the details, though we might assume the "op-amp" has input clamp diodes, so that V<sub>REF</sub> is constrained by V<sub>K</sub>.  The equivalent schematic on the following page,

[image: LM431 equivalent circuit]

does show the diode (Q7 B-C), though not the A-K diode (perhaps also assumed, as an intrinsic (substrate) diode?).  The diagram [currently on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL431),

[image: TL431 equivalent circuit]

shows both diodes explicitly.  Though it also shows the effective internal reference as a current source symbol for some reason?  Well, it's only Wikipedia I guess.

Anyway, we can imagine the basic operation of this device akin to an NPN BJT, where anode is "emitter", REF is "base" and cathode is "collector".  "V<sub>BE</sub>" is large yet *suspiciously* stable (2.50V, hardly varies with I<sub>K</sub> or T<sub>J</sub>), h<sub>FE</sub> is very large (hence low I<sub>REF</sub>), and there's a built-in "B-C" diode (actually literally true, according to the equivalent diagram!) which defines "V<sub>CE(sat)</sub>" -- cathode can never pull below a V<sub>BE</sub> below V<sub>REF</sub>, else it pulls down on REF itself, thus limiting further saturation.  That is, say we leave cathode open and bias up REF: it will pull up to 2.5V, and cathode will be pulled along, one diode drop below; current flows from REF into K, and we'll measure 2.5V on REF and about 1.8V on K.

Note that "base" current therefore increases in saturation.  Does this violate the "large h<sub>FE</sub>" statement above?  Well, perhaps, but like a real BJT, h<sub>FE</sub> falls precipitously in saturation.  In this case, it's falling from a very high value (thousands) to zero.  That's arguably the same thing, just dialed up to an extreme!

### In the given circuit

Now we can apply this knowledge.  We have two cases.  Either:

1. Cathode is pulled high by a voltage source, forcing it out of saturation
2. Cathode saturates, pulling down on REF (saturating as described above)

In case 1, either the cathode current rating (100mA) is exceeded, or high power flows and temperature quickly rises above the rating.  In case 2, REF current takes over.  If the REF source violates maximum REF current, expect failure again.

In the given circuit, the divider shall have low enough Thevenin resistance that REF current produces an acceptably small error (which, for a crude voltage sensor, could be 10% or more; for precision applications, you'd want it comparable or less than the tolerance of the device), while also being high enough that, at maximum input voltage, the REF current rating is honored.  Between ~µA and 10mA, that should be pretty easy to achieve.

We also prefer a low divider current to minimize power dissipation.

Comment: [TL431, TL432 Precision Programmable Reference](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf?ts=1683958751138) rev. 2022/07 features a "Detailed Schematic" on page 20.

Comment: When I see all the transistors I am asking myself how sensible is this input stage to EMI.

Comment: @TomBenDan That's a separate question, but yes, these are sensitive to RF rectification. It is sometimes necessary to add a small capacitor from REF to A to shunt noise; usually 100-470pF. Too much adversely affects the AC response.

Comment: Well, this is an important thing to consider. This is an input stage used in a 24 V automotive system. It is supposed to pass EMC immunity tests, some of them very nasty, such as 2-200 MHz with 100 V/m and 200 MHZ-18 GHz with 200 V/m, not to mention a bunch of conducted susceptibility tests.

Comment: Ah, indeed. Some capacitors strewn about -- minding their effect upon the intended circuit of course -- may be prudent for that. Then, note that 600V might not be required, but most likely is limited by adjacent transient protection devices -- ISO 7637-2 test pulse 1 is -600V at only 50 ohms, easily shunted. Likewise 3b (+200V).

Answer (score 3):

I expect the \$V_{REF}\$ terminal voltage to be clamped not to exceed 2.5 V significantly even in open loop mode like depicted if the current into it stays below the absolute maximum of 10 mA.
(600 V may need a high voltage resistor or several series connected ones, and careful layout; current shouldn't exceed 1.2 mA.)

For 100 V, 100 kΩ limits to 1 mA; for a threshold of 18 V, a divider of 110  kΩ & 16 kΩ comes close.

[Using the TL431 for Undervoltage and Overvoltage Detection](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva987a/slva987a.pdf?ts=1683988084672) contains information on **TL**431 in comparator mode, including

> CAUTION
> This is the most common question for TL431:
> What is the max voltage on the TL431 REF pin?
> Answer: There is no max voltage on REF pin because it
> depends on the ABS max \$I_{ref}\$ current. See for design considerations and
> examples for \$I_{ref}\$.

Comment: I made a rough estimation close to yours, 100 kΩ and 15 kΩ.
But still, at 100 V the voltage will be 12.7 V which is way above the 5 V in the example shown, not to mention that practically at the LM431 cathode it will be less after the resistor and the optocoupler's LED.

Comment: \$I_{REF}\$ is up to about .1 mA in regular operation - I take the absolute max rating to mean the voltage at the \$V_{REF}\$ terminal will be clamped (to one \$V_{BE}\$ above the internal reference voltage?) (AN in answer plots \$V_{IN}\$ ("other end of resistor") instead.) Datasheets … differ … even  from a single manufacturer.

Comment: Yes, I found some discussions in the TI technical forums too.
The concern is not the voltage at \$V_{REF}\$ but the current, this is why the data sheet specifies the max. \$I_{REF}\$.
But still there is a parameter that needs attention, it seems that the \$V_{REF}\$ must be smaller than the voltage at the output, or \$V_{KA}\$.
If it is like in the example 5 V and the \$V_{REF}\$ at 100 V will be approx. 12.5 V I think that it is an illegal condition.

Comment: Yes, it \$V_{REF}\$ will be higher than \$V_Z\$/\$V_{KA}\$ here even at 2.5 V, which is not recommended *for voltage regulator (closed loop) operation*. No, it will not rise to 12.5 V due to increasing \$I_{REF}\$.

Comment: Perhaps I will explain the application.
I need to bring an input from a 24 V automotive electrical system to a microcontroller input. The input is active above 18 V. 
It must stand ESD and 100 V load dump pulses.
Right now I am using a solution based on optocouplers with several components and I have a PCB space problem. I also don't like the optocoupler solution as it has some sensitivities. I need to make sure the optocoupler also won't trigger below 18 V, solved with a zener in series. 
I want to use a MOSFET triggered by the LM431. I am not at all sure it will take much less space.

Answer (score 2):

The absolute maximum ratings section of the TI datasheet is remarkably vague on this detail. But it does seem to imply that the output voltage should not be less than Vref.

If you look at the equivalent schematic, it shows that there is basically only the B-C junction of an NPN transistor between those two pins. You'd be forward biasing this junction, clamping Vref to one diode drop above the output voltage in any case. This shouldn't harm anything as long as the source resistance driving Vref is high enough to limit the current to a safe value.

Comment: Yes, I checked the data sheets from several producers of this part, none mention this parameter. Weird, same thing about other versions like LMV431, TL431, etc.